# Class ForEachInt a in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am having difficulties in doing an exercise. I know I have to define the signatures of the functions except the function feget, but I do not know how to do it.

I have to set the `ForEachInt` class that describes the crossing to structures
data that store integers and that includes the following functions:

- `felength` (the number of elements in the structure)
- `fehead` (the first integer in the structure)
- `fetail` (the structure without the first integer)
- `fe2list` (returns the Whole structure in a list)
- `feget` (all ith according felist).

This is what i have done:

`class ForEachInt a where 
data ForEachInt = Empty | Int Int Int`

Thank U.

Comment: "A past exam"... yea sure.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows no attempt at research or solving the presented problem.

Comment: I'm studying for a new exam, through previous exams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be wishing to create an all-`Int` list class. Very well:

```
data ForEachInt = None | Some Int ForEachInt
```

This defines the datatype for us, allowing us to chain `Int`s together using the `Some` constructor. From then, it's easy:

```
felength :: ForEachInt -> Int
felength None        = 0
felength (Some x xs) = 1 + (felength xs)

fehead :: ForEachInt -> Int
fehead (Some x xs) = x
fehead None        = error "Cannot retrieve from None"

fetail :: ForEachInt -> ForEachInt
fetail (Some x xs) = xs
fetail None        = error "Cannot retrieve from None"

fe2list :: ForEachInt -> [Int]
fe2list None        = []
fe2list (Some x xs) = x : fe2list xs
```

I recommend studying each of these functions carefully: the recursion can easily confuse one. As for the pattern matching, that's easy, but the actually data structure is the hardest to understand, I find. LYAH has a good explanation of datatypes, so check that out.

Comment: Thanks, now I realized what I was missing. I was focus the exercise as an exercise on lists.